# How can I notify client side so that a certain post does not exist anymore?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, core-data, client-server

The app I made is post/thread based. Every time a client submits a post, all the other clients receive the post as they refresh the `tableview`. The newly received post is then saved using core data. Ultimately, for every client that refreshes, the function `fetchPosts` is called. `fetchPost` is an asynchronous function that returns a callback twice. First, when it receives posts from core data and then when server sync is finished and the live data has been received.

The problem with this function is that it will always return in the first callback all the posts, **including** the one that was deleted (by other clients).

What is a proper way to deal with that? Here is my code:

```
static func fetchPosts(lastPost:Topic?,subject:String,complition: @escaping (_ topics:[Topic?],_ newData:Bool)->()){

        var topics:[Topic?] = []

        //Check Ceche. FIRST PART
        do {
            let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<DPost> = DPost.fetchRequest()
            fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 20
            if lastPost == nil {
                fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "created < %@ AND subject = %@ ", NSDate(),subject)
            }else{
                fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "created < %@ AND subject = %@", argumentArray: [lastPost?.date as Any, subject])
            }

            let fetchedResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            // _ = index
            for (_, aPost) in fetchedResults.enumerated() {

                topics.append(Topic(id: aPost.id!, title: aPost.title!, date: aPost.created! as Date, image: aPost.imageAddress, posterUsername: aPost.username!, posterUserid: aPost.userId!,posterImage: aPost.posterImageAddress))
                //TODO: add subject id
            }
        }
        catch {
            print ("fetch task failed", error)
        }
        //First Callback
        complition(topics,true)

        //Second part
        //Check server.
        topics = []
        var data:[String:Any] = [:]
        data[K.UserInformation.sessionID] = User.currentUser!.sessionID
        data[K.UserInformation.udid] = User.currentUser?.udid
        if topics.last == nil {
            data[K.TopicInformation.data] = "000000000000000000000000"
        }  else  {
            data[K.TopicInformation.data] = lastPost?.id
        }
        data[K.TopicInformation.subject] = subject
        HTTPRequest.appSession.data_request(url_to_request: K.Server.domain+":8443/getPosts",method: HTTPRequest.HTTPRequestMethod.post, data: HTTPRequest.toJSON(dict: data)) { (resStr:String?) in
            // return respond with information about the registrant status.
            if resStr != nil{
                let respond = HTTPRequest.toDict(jsonStr: resStr!)
                if (respond[K.Status.success] != nil){
                    let postDictList = respond[K.Status.success] as! [[String:Any]]
                    if postDictList.count == 0  {
                        //Second callback
                        complition(topics,true)
                        return
                    }
                    for dict in postDictList  {
                        let formatter = DateFormatter()
                        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

                        var topic:Topic? = nil
                        if let date = formatter.date(from: dict[K.TopicInformation.date] as! String) {
                            context.mergePolicy = NSOverwriteMergePolicy
                            let cPost = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "CDPost", into: context) as! DPost
                            cPost.id = dict[K.TopicInformation.id] as? String
                            cPost.title = dict[K.TopicInformation.title] as? String
                            cPost.created = date as NSDate
                            cPost.imageAddress = dict[K.TopicInformation.postImageAddress] as? String
                            cPost.username = dict[K.TopicInformation.posterUsername] as? String
                            cPost.userId = dict[K.TopicInformation.posterUserid] as? String
                            cPost.posterImageAddress = dict[K.TopicInformation.posterImageAddress] as? String
                            cPost.subject = dict[K.TopicInformation.subject] as? String
                            do{
                                try context.save()
                            }
                            catch{
                                fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                            }

                            topic = Topic(id: dict[K.TopicInformation.id] as! String,
                                          title: dict[K.TopicInformation.title] as! String,
                                          date: date,
                                          image: dict[K.TopicInformation.postImageAddress] as? String,
                                          posterUsername: dict[K.TopicInformation.posterUsername] as! String,
                                          posterUserid: dict[K.TopicInformation.posterUserid] as! String, posterImage: dict[K.TopicInformation.posterImageAddress] as? String)
                        }
                        topics.append(topic!)
                    }
                    complition(topics,true)
                    return
                }

                if(respond[K.Status.error] != nil){
                    print(respond["errmsg"] as! String)
                }
            }
```

The server side is written with NodeJS Mongodb is the database I'm using. Let me know if it's relevant so can edit out/in some tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have fetch limit, I dont think you can do it locally by compare the fetched posts and the stored posts in your CoreData, best is add an `unread` tag to the post and update it with your API, when fetch then can fetch both deleted and normal posts with `unread` tag, another idea is use last logged in time and fetch all post from that time, including deleted post

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Ill wait for some more ideas for solutions. If not one will have a better idea I will mark as solution.

Comment: If you can upvote this post, I want to post some questions but Because i have alot of posts with 0 upvotes I cant post anything...